# ContentStringFormat binding doesn't refresh on propertychange

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having an issue causing a label to refresh when it's content doesn't change but its format does. The ContentStringFormat property is bound to the viewmodel and the property change is notified, but the label doesn't update, please find bellow a minimal reproduction exemple in code as well as a project ready to compile/run that demonstrates the issue.

Download project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjs1lot09uc2lgj/WPFFormatBindingRefresh.zip?dl=0

XAML :

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding FirstLabelContent}"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding SecondLabelContent}" ContentStringFormat="{Binding SecondLabelFormatContent}"></Label>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add "test" to all bound elements</Button>        
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind :

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (a,b)=> { }; // empty handler avoids checking for null when raising

    public string FirstLabelContent { get; set; } = "First Label";
    public string SecondLabelContent { get; set; } = "Second";
    public string SecondLabelFormatContent { get; set; } = "{0} Label";

    void PropertyChange(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstLabelContent += " TEST";
        SecondLabelFormatContent += " TEST";
        PropertyChange("FirstLabelContent"); // First label correctly updates
        PropertyChange("SecondLabelFormatContent"); // Second label doesn't update, expected behavior is changing the format string should cause an update
    }
```

Comment: Did you check VS output to see if there is some binding error? or any xaml warning for it?

Comment: @Mishka no warnings, runs just fine before updating so the binding is fine too, not a typo error as i get this issue on every occurence in my real project and as you can see the repro example could hardly be simpler

Comment: Perhaps you need to raise PropertyChanged for SecondLabelContent, otherwise it doesnt "get" the stringformat again?

Comment: @Mishka That's not possible to do because the secondlabelcontent does not change, which is why i want an UI update on that changing, i produced a simple reproduction example as it is the standard way to show an issue but in my real project figuring out the 100s of properties that would have to be changed is a no go, i'm databound to the formatstring, i expect it to update when it changes, it's the way it works for anything else in wpf so i'm trying to see if i stumbled on a wpf bug or if i'm doing something wrong and if there is a workaround.

Comment: Workaround: Use a `MultiBinding` and format the text yourself

Comment: @DennisKuypers Care to expand / give a code example? It needs to update on notifying change only on the format part (i'm using this for custom localisation).

Comment: You could put both the input and the formatting into a `MultiBinding` and then use a custom `IMultiValueConverter` to format the text. Does this help? Maybe you can look into best practices for localization, because the MultiBinding is not very handy.

Comment: @DennisKuypers all the standard ways of localisation are based around ressources dictionaries or pretty heavy libraries, neither of which fits the bill. A multibinding doesn't directly help as the stringformat property of the multibinding isn't a dependency property either (so can't bind to it). Could you post a sample of what you have in mind?

Comment: mm8 provided an answer with the way that I thought of ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Label` doesn't support refreshing the `ContentStringFormat` through a binding.

You could use a multi converter like this:

```
public class MultiConverter2 : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string SecondLabelContent = values[0] as string;
        string SecondLabelFormatContent = values[1] as string;

        return string.Format(SecondLabelFormatContent, SecondLabelContent);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:MultiConverter2 x:Key="conv" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Label Content="{Binding FirstLabelContent}"></Label>
    <Label>
        <Label.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                <Binding Path="SecondLabelContent" />
                <Binding Path="SecondLabelFormatContent" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add "test" to all bound elements</Button>
</StackPanel>
```